# How can I track which process is calling another process (Linux)?

Tags: linux, process

My computer is getting really laggy with a `sendmail` process (it's using 10% memory and 20% CPU all the time). I tried the following:

1. Stopping the service -> Futile. The service doesn't exist.
2. Killing the process -> Useless. The process restarts itself.
3. Removing the software -> Fatal. It tries to take 700MB along with it.
4. Renaming the binary -> Works. But it's a temporary solution.

I'm trying to identify which process is making the call to the `sendmail` process. How can I find the culprit?

The distro is Fedora 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Fedora as well. I usually call `pgrep -x process` then find those processes listed with `ps -A`.

Comment: This is so intriguing... it says bash is being responsible for running this process...

Comment: The next step is an entirely different issue, but your answer helped immensely. Cool name.

Comment: Is it a system startup process? You can use
`pstree`
-or-
`ps -H`
-or-
`ps aux | grep sendmail`
-or-
`ps auxww | grep sendmail`

Let me play around a bit, see what I can find. You may want something deeper than I am thinking.

Comment: Thanks. This is the way bash is running the process `/usr/bin/bash /usr/sbin/sendmail -FCronDaemon -i -odi -oem -oi -t -f root`

Comment: I am not too familiar with that daemon. I usually find what I need with `top` in the terminal, then what I linked at first to determine what all it's coinciding with at that time. Do you have a beefy system, or it is truly slowing down your rig?

On a side note, here is a process list I keep in my favorites; sorry I didn't link at first, I had to find it: [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x5368.htm).

Comment: It freezes every couple minutes for 3 to 5. Maybe I'm being picky, but it's very noticeable since it didn't use to do this. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. Renaming the binary solves the issue but I need to find the real culprit... (not bash)

Comment: I would look into the /var/ folder for some sendmail log. See if it is eating up your resources trying to do something; the log can likely identify. Maybe it is stuck in a retreive mail or send mail loop or accessing a server and keeps failing only to try again and again. Your system shouldn't be freezing, especially Fedora 30.

Comment: `/var/log/maillog-XXXXXXXX` doesn't show anything relevant, but I did found some crontab processes that I forgot to remove months ago (that ran every minute :/). It didn't fix the lag, but it improved some other things. Still laggy because of sendmail. I'll keep looking into it.